# Is my OCaml code compiled in 64 bits

Tags: string, ocaml

I am compiling with `ocamlc` a (ocaml) code involving hashtables, that become quite large at runtime.

Even though the equivalent runs perfectly well in C# (compiled in 64 bits), I suspect that my OCaml code is compiled in 32 bits, responsible for throwing memory errors, whereas the memory usage is low (around 2GB when the exception is thrown).

How can I make sure that the produced .exe is compiled in 64 bits ?

**Edit.** The bug occurs soon after the largest hashtable reaches `14 344 207` elements.

Comment: You should show us the exception raised.  For word size, check `Sys.word_size`.  If it is 32, your compiler set is 32-bits.

Comment: Thanks you, it returned 32. If you post it as an answer, I can validate it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the compiler's word size by `Sys.word_size`:

```
val word_size : int
(** Size of one word on the machine currently executing the OCaml
   program, in bits: 32 or 64. *)
```

"Size of one word on the machine" is misleading.  If the compiler is 32bits, `word_size = 32` even the machine architecture is 64bits.